# What is $s$ in s-energy (eg. Riesz s-energy)

Tags: geometry, optimization, potential-theory

I'm trying to understand [fekete problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fekete_problem). There is a variable $s$ and a related concept of 's-energy' [[1]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1447v2.pdf) [[2]](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0503063) [[3]](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10444-007-9057-0#page-1) [[4]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904503000315) that comes up repeatedly when borrowing the concept of potential energy to find well separated point sets on a sphere. The problem is, though I can find some references to 's-energy', I can't find a definition of $s$ and don't know how to determine its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of $s$ is up to you; different choices of $s$ will produce different energy-minimizing  configurations of points. The larger $s$ is, the more we penalize the *smallest* distances between points (without paying that much attention to the distances that are not smallest). In the limit $s\to\infty$ the energy minimization problem becomes the maxmin problem 
$$\min_{i<j} |x_i-x_j|\to\max $$
If you take inspiration from electrostatics, thinking of points as unit charges that repel one another, then you should use $s=N-2$ where $N$ is the dimension of the ambient space. This is known as Newtonian or Couloumbian energy. The value $s=N-2$ is the one most often used in potential theory.

On the other hand, for computation of derivatives it may help to have $s$ that is an even integer, because then $|x_i-x_j|^{-s}$ is a rational function:  square root cancels out.