# Is s-energy, specifically logarithmic energy, based on function -log(d) or log(d) with distance d?

Tags: logarithms, nonlinear-optimization

[There was an earlier question about s-energy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872849/what-is-s-in-s-energy-eg-riesz-s-energy); I think I got the point.

However, in various problem settings I see one is interested maximising pairwise distances between points and, there they say, thus logarithmic energy is minimized. Doesn't log *grow* with distance? To me  this means that actually one is speaking about -log(d) where d is distance, isn't he? Is this a convention of some sort?

When logarithmic potentials are in question, are points always considered to be of like sign? I haven't seen any work on oppositely "charged" logarithmic points or sources, whatever they are called. Is this because of the missing practical applications?

Thank you!